# Moment Of Inertia Specifications AISC

Tags: beam, specifications

Is there some regulatory body/inspection that verifies the AISC specified Moment(s) of Inertia for steel I-Beams?  So for example, if a mill produces a W8x21 and says hey, it meets the specs, it's 8 in Deep and is 21 lbs/ft, and because I say so, it has Moment Of 75 in^4.

Does anybody actually go in a caliper the flange width/thickness web thickness/depth and fillet profile to get some idea whether this manufacturer is within a percent +/- of the spec? Like particularly if their fillet building process ends up putting an extra half pound per foot of material?